# How to prevent an administrator from logging in twice?

Tags: php, sql, session

I don't want to show the administrator the login page if they're already logged in.
What should I do if I want to redirect the administrator to the homepage when they go to the administrator login page. For your information, I have included the `header.php` into every administrator pages after the administrator has logged in. Your help is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Below shows a part of my `header.php` coding:

```
<?php             
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name']) or (!isset($_SESSION['password'])) 
  or $_SESSION['name'] == '' or $_SESSION['password'] == '' )       
    {
            header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Below shows my administrator login page coding:

```
<form method="post" action="login_now.php" name="form1" id="form1" onSubmit="MM_validateForm('Name','','R','Password','','R','Security_code','','R');return document.MM_returnValue"> 


  <table style="width: 100%;">      

  <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4"><img src="../admin/images/login.png" alt="Please enter your login details."></td>
      </tr>

           <tr>

             <td>

             Username<span class="required">*</span>

             <br>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; height: 20px" name="Name" id="Name" class="inputstyle"/>

            <br>
            <br>

               Password<span class="required">*</span>

           <br>

        <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; height: 20px" name="Password" id="Password" class="inputstyle"/>

        <br>


             </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <br> </td>
</tr>     

<tr>

      <td align="right" width="240px">  

       <input type="submit" value="Login" class="buttons" />
```

Below shows my `login_now.php` coding:

```
<?php session_start(); 
  ob_start();
  include("../DBScripts/DB.php");
    $adminName = $_POST['Name'];
    $adminPassword = $_POST['Password'];
  $Security = $_POST['Security_code'];
  $hidden = $_POST['Security_required'];

    $conn = dbConnect();

    if (!$conn)
        die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

    $query = "select * from user where usernm='$adminName' and userpw='$adminPassword'";   
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);   
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 && $row['userty']== user && $Security == $hidden)
    {     
    $_SESSION['name'] = $adminName;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $adminPassword;
    header ('Location: ../Users/home_user.php');
   } 
    else if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 && $row['userty']== admin && $Security == $hidden)
    {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $adminName;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $adminPassword;
        header('Location: adminindex.php');
      }
    else
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

?>
```

Comment: Do the opposite check on the login page?! *If already logged in, redirect to homepage...*

Comment: [Do you see the big "DO NOT USE THIS" red box in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)?

Comment: Redirect the admin back to `adminindex` if session exists.

Comment: May I know how do I redirect the admin back to adminindex if session? I would appreciate very much very much if you answer me in code value. @Nil'z

Comment: May I know how do I do an opposite check on the login page? Could you answer me code in value. Much appreciated. Thanks! @deceze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new session that is admin specific.

on login, set a new `$_SESSION['admin'] = true` when an admin logs in (set with other sessions)

then on the login page,

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] === true) # || is the same as the or operator
    header('Location: yournonloginpage.php');
```

Comment: `&& is the same as the or operator` I know PHP is bad, but surely it's not *that* bad?

Comment: PHP isn't bad, it's just not the most beautifull language to write ;)

Comment: I'm just having a hard time reconciling `and and` being `the same as the or operator`.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would suggest is that you never want to store password information in a session. The password should only be used to authenticate the login action and even this comparison should be hashed.

Aside from this, you're almost there with what you have. If a user has logged in and you've stored their username in `$_SESSION`, you can just test `isset($_SESSION['name'])`, then redirect as desired. Just make sure to implement a logout function which unsets `$_SESSION['name']`.

If I understand what you're asking, you'll just want to insert this in your login page, and remove the header.php from the rest of your pages:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
```

This will make it impossible to access the login page while already logged in. If `$_SESSION['name']` is initialized and is not null, you have a user logged in, otherwise not.

Then you'll want to provide a logout page, simplest method is to create a link somewhere called logout which links to logout.php which might contain:

```
unset($_SESSION['name']);
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: Ok i will remove password information in the session. May I have the answer in code value as I am still quite confused with your explanation? Thanks!

Comment: I added some examples to my answer

Comment: It works! I will do more research on secure login page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check like this if session is already created and set and then redirect the user back to the `adminindex` page, You have to check this in the login page:

```
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['name'] != "" )
{
        header('Location: adminindex.php');
        die;
}
```

Comment: My bad, you need a `die` statement after redirecting. :D